# Kinetic energy of a yoyo

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, free-body-diagram, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

[image]

Consider the yoyo above:

The yoyo is constructed from two heavy disks of radius
R
connected by a light axle
of radius
r
, as shown in the figure below. The total mass of the yoyo is
M
and its
moment of inertia for rotations around the axle can be taken to be $$\frac12MR^2$$

as it is spinning and rotating and travelling downwards i am aware that the total kinetic energy is as follows:

$$\frac12 Iw^2 +\frac12mv^2$$

is the v term wR or wr?

Comment: *[...] and its moment of inertia for rotations around the axle can be taken to be [...]* It rotates about the centre of the yoyo.

Comment: Find the instantaneous axis of rotation

Answer (score 1):

$v$ would be equal to $\omega$ multiplied by the radius of the axle.

In reality the radius of the axle would likely be somewhere in between $r$ and $R$. The reason being that as the yoyo string wraps around the axle, it would essentially increase the circumference and radius of the axle, as the string wrapped around the axle can be treated as part of the axle in this example.

However, if you were to say that the string around the axle is negligible (or if you are calculating this right at the instant when the yoyo has completely unwound all of the string), then it would be simply $\omega r$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
let’s start by defining some important points in the problem ! let the point of contact of the string with the yo-yo be named as $A$ and the centre of the yo-yo be called as $C$ , assuming a symmetric mass distribution in yo-yo the centre of mass of the yo-yo coincides with $C$ due to symmetry !

Now coming to the energy part ! as mentioned by you energy can be expressed as the sum of rotational $KE$ and translational $KE$ , i.e , $\frac{Iw^{2}}{2} + \frac{Mv^{2}}{2}$ ; that’s correct but what do we do about the linear velocity $v$ , we’ll as the contact point $A$ is on the string as well as the yo-yo we have that it is stationary hence it’s $v_{a}=0$ and we also know that $v_{a}=v - \omega r$ equating the two we get $v=wr$ ! had it been the case that the string had been in contact with the outer rim we would have $R$ in place of $r$ in the expression of $v$

an alternate method that can be used in this case to avoid any kind of such confusion is using the fact that $A$ is the instantaneous centre of rotation so $KE = \frac{I_{A}w^{2}}{2}$